# Unknown recieiver 'indexPath'l did you mean NSIndexPath?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, ios5

I'm parsing something right now and i want to display it in a cell i', using this code for my tableview but i also want it without Tablview

```
    NSString *const JsonDataUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", appdownloadurl];
    NSString *jsonString = [NSString 
                            stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:JsonDataUrl] 
                            encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                            error:nil];

    SBJSON *parser = [[SBJSON alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *results = [parser objectWithString:jsonString error:nil];

    parser = nil;

    [self setTableData:[results objectForKey:@"resultCount"]];
```

This works great but when i place this line in viewdidload

```
NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSLog(@"Apple: %@", [item objectForKey:@"price"]);
```

And error shows up on this line;

```
NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

//Unknown recieiver 'indexPath'l did you mean NSIndexPath?

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Show the method signature. If there is no 'indexPath' variable as argument, and if you don't declare it locally, I guess the error message is pretty clear...

Answer (score 0):

Do you declare any variable called `indexPath` in your `viewDidLoad` method? You can't just use the `indexPath` from your table view methods in `viewDidLoad` arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];` suggests you are trying to load from an `NSArray`, you probably want to try something like:

```
NSDictionary *item = [tableData objectForKey:@"Some Key"];
```